# Indy SMTP server - how to detect CC & BCC recipients?

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy10

I am trying to develop an SMTP relay server using the Delphi help, Indy examples and Google.

I am just beginning and have a dummy SMTP client which sends a test message to an SMTP server which will later process it and forward it using an SMTP relay.

At the server, I receive one `OnRcpt` for each recipient (I test with one `To`, one `CC` and one `Bcc`).

I also see the `To` and `CC` recipients in `AMsg` when I handle `OnMsgReceive` and convert `AMsg` to a `TStringStream` (suitably prefixed with `To:` and `CC:`), but I don't see the `BCC` there.

Question: how do I tell which addresses were `To`, `CC` and `BCC`?

---

Here's some exceedingly simple code. I am setting breakpoints & examining received parameters to try to see what is happing

```
procedure TEmailMonitorMainForm.IdSMTPServerMsgReceive(ASender: TIdSMTPServerContext;
  AMsg: TStream; var VAction: TIdDataReply);
var
  LMsg : TIdMessage;
begin
  LMsg := TIdMessage.Create(Nil);
  LMsg.LoadFromStream(AMsg);
  LMsg.Free();   // breakpoint here  examine   Lmsg
end;         // IdSMTPServerMsgReceive()
```

[Update]  when I send, then `<message>.BCCList.Count = 1`, but when I Receive, it is 0, whereas the received `CClist.Count` is 1, as it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At the server, I receive one OnRcpt for each recipient (I test with one To, one CC and one Bcc).

The SMTP protocol does not distinguish between `To`, `CC`, and `BCC` recipients.  That is an artifact of the email format via its `To:` and `Cc:` headers (there is no `Bcc:` header, though `TIdMessage.SaveToFile()` creates one so `TIdMessage.LoadFromFile()` can re-load it).  When an SMTP client sends an email to an SMTP server, the client determines the intended recipients and specifies each one in a separate `RCPT TO` command to the server (that is what allows `BCC` to work - there is no `Bcc:` header in the email itself, but the server is given a `RCPT TO` command for each `Bcc` recipient).  The `RCPT TO` addresses are the values specified in the `TIdSMTPServer.OnRcptTo` event, and are collected in the `TIdSMTPServerContext.RCPTList` property.  These addresses are explicitly requested by the SMTP client, and are the only addresses you should deliver the email to (not the recipients specified in the email headers).

> I also see the To and CC recipients in AMsg when I handle OnMsgReceive and convert AMsg to a TStringStream (suitably prefixed with To: and CC:), but I don't see the BCC there.

The actual email itself is just arbitrary data as far as an SMTP server is concerned.  It is meant to be delivered as-is to each requested recipient.  That is why the email data is provided as a `TStream` in the `TIdSMTPServer.OnMsgReceive` event, and why `TIdSMTPServer` in Indy 10 does not provide `TIdMessage`-based events like it did in Indy 9 and earlier.

If the email is in an [RFC 822/2822/5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) format (which it usually is), it will have `To:` and `Cc:` headers.  When receiving/loading such an email into a `TIdMessage`, those headers are used to fill in the `TIdMessage.Recipients` and `TIdMessage.CCList` properties, respectively.  But since there is usually no `Bcc:` header (unless the email is being loaded from a file created by `TIdMessage.SaveToFile()`), the `TIdMessage.BCCList` will not be filled in.

> how do I tell which addresses were To, CC and BCC?

Since the SMTP protocol itself does not distinguish between the different recipient types, the only way for you to distinguish between them is to parse the email, looking at its `To:` and `Cc:` headers.  Any address in the `TIdSMTPServerContext.RCPTList` property that is not in one of those two headers must be a `Bcc` recipient.  However, there is no guarantee that the other addresses in the `TIdSMTPServerContext.RCPTList` property will always match the `To:` and `Cc:` headers (though they usually will), since technically an SMTP client can send whatever raw data it wants and the SMTP will deliver it as-is without caring what it actually contains.

> Here's some exceedingly simple code.

**DO NOT** use `TIdMessage.LoadFromStream()` to parse the `TStream` object provided by the `TIdSMTPServer.OnMsgReceive` event!  It will not always work correctly.  The technical reason has been discussed in detail multiple times in the Embarcadero and AToZed forums, for example in [this discussion](http://forums2.atozed.com/viewtopic.php?t=26149).  You need to use the following workaround for the time being.  The issue will be addressed in Indy 11:

```
procedure TEmailMonitorMainForm.IdSMTPServerMsgReceive(ASender: TIdSMTPServerContext; AMsg: TStream; var VAction: TIdDataReply);
var
  LMsg : TIdMessage;
  LClient: TIdMessageClient;
  LIO: TIdIOHandlerStreamMsg;
begin
  LMsg := TIdMessage.Create(Nil);
  try
    //LMsg.LoadFromStream(AMsg);    
    LClient := TIdMessageClient.Create;
    try
      LIO := TIdIOHandlerStreamMsg.Create(LClient, AMsg);
      LIO.FreeStreams := False;
      LIO.EscapeLines := True;
      LIO.Open;
      LClient.IOHandler := LIO;
      LClient.ProcessMessage(LMsg, False);
    finally
      LClient.Free;
    end;
    // now you can use LMsg as needed...
  finally
    LMsg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: wow, need to adapt some of my projects here, didn't know of this about OnMsgReceive...

Comment: @Remmy Thanks, as always, for a full and informative answer. This should be extremely helpful to others.   Any news on the arrival of Indy 11?   Any suggested reading material on SMTP servers, especially with Indy (other than the easily Googlable)?